# How to call Section from Label used in Function in NSIS?

Tags: installation, nsis

I am comparing the version check in the Function called by .onInit, If this version check tells machine has older version then i would like uninstall the older version. How to achieve this?? my method is if older version is present then messagebox displays u have older version installed click ok to install new version or cancel to continue with the old version. IDOK ok IDCANCEL cancel ok: ExecWait Uninstal ; executes uninstall.exe cancel: Abort ; continue wid olde version.

problem here is ExecWait is getting executed parallely wid newer version installation. (both r becuming 2 diff threads)

for this i wanted to include only Section Uninstall inside the label of the function to uninstall silently.

Please guide me how to call Section from the Function.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a section but you can do this:

```
Function MySectionCode
# My code goes here
FunctionEnd

Function .onInit
call MySectionCode
FunctionEnd

Section "MySection"
call MySectionCode
SectionEnd
```

And just to be clear, ExecWait **always** waits for the child process but sometimes the child process starts its children and does not wait for them. To wait for a NSIS uninstaller you need to use the special [_?= parameter](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/When_I_use_ExecWait_uninstaller.exe_it_doesn%27t_wait_for_the_uninstaller).

Comment: _?= parameter takes $INSTDIR  value but $INSTDIR is different for each version might be because of this Exec is not waiting for the uninstaller to get uninstalled.